# What is the difference between "gravitas" and "mien"?

Tags: meaning, usage, vocabulary

Take CAMBRIDGE DICTIONARY, for example:

GRAVITAS:

Definition: seriousness and importance of manner, causing feelings of respect and trust in others

MIEN:
Definition: general appearance and manner, especially the expression on their face, which shows what they are feeling or thinking

EXAMPLES:

GRAVITAS:

1. There is a certain amount of gravitas to a page that you don't get on a screen.
2. He's an effective enough politician but somehow he lacks the statesmanlike gravitas of a world leader

MIEN:

1. His aristocratic mien and expensive clothes singled him out.
2. She saw a man now--wild, white, intense as fire, with some terrible cool kind of deadliness in his mien.

In each of these examples, "gravitas" and "mien" seem to convey a shared sense of "one's attitude, behavior, and manners they put on when in public".

Comment: Isn't 'gravitas' a particular example of 'mien'?

Comment: The answer is In the question. Mien is a general term that merely includes gravitas. It may also include other characteristics such as flippancy, disrespect, humbleness, belligerence, elation etc.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying, to make it easier to see the difference: *mien* is loosely equivalent to *appearance* (but see below), and you can think of *gravitas* as (more or less) *impressiveness*.

Note: *mien* is more than the appearance you would see in a photograph -- it also includes the way the person carries himself and acts.

So, *gravitas* is a specific type of *mien*.  That is, *mien* is more general.